# Cross-compiling cairo for x86_64-w64 with mingw

Tags: linker, cross-compiling, cairo, mingw-w64

I have an application that links again SDL and cairo that I would like to cross-compile on ubuntu for win64.  I used [this excellent blog post](http://neboverflow.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/crosscompiling-c-based-sdl2-game.html) to get SDL cross compiling and I've used [another blog post](http://rodrigorivas.serveblog.net/en/mingw-cross-compiler/) to cross-compile zlib, libpng and libpixman.

However, I now get a linker error trying to compile [my minimal test program](https://gist.github.com/hertzsprung/6d80b1988bf7b50f8d03):

```
$ make cairotest.exe 
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o cairotest.o -c cairotest.c -I/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2 -Dmain=SDL_main -I/home/jshaw/x86_64-w64/include/cairo -I/home/jshaw/x86_64-w64/include/pixman-1 -I/home/jshaw/x86_64-w64/include/libpng16 
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o cairotest.exe cairotest.o -L/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -mwindows -L/home/jshaw/x86_64-w64/lib -lcairo 
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:13: recipe for target 'cairotest.exe' failed
```

I should mention that this test program works correctly if I just use SDL2 without any cairo code, so I suspect something is wrong with the cairo library that I cross-compiled.  How should I go about diagnosing the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your Makefile it appears as though your are using normal `pkg-config` for discovering your Cairo libs. `CAIRO_LDFLAGS := $(shell $(PKG_CONFIG) cairo --libs)`. This will find the path to your *host* libraries, which is presumably a different architecture than the target. An architecture mismatch like that can really cause strange problems with the linker. I believe you should be looking for something like `usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/pkg-config`.

Other things to try;

Run the compilation commands manually, as the makefile could be suppressing output.

Also, when running the command, add the `-v` flag to the command line to get the verbose output to better figure out where the issue is.